# Visual Studio 2013 Database Project - UDTT - FileStream Column Issue

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2013, database-project

I am having a problem creating a User Defined Table Type with a FILESTREAM column in my Visual Studio 2013 (Update 4) Database Project.

I have added a FILEGROUP containing a FILESTREAM to the project, and configured this as the default filestream filegroup via the project settings > database settings > operational tab.

The create table syntax is as below:

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[MediaType] AS TABLE (
[Guid] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
[MediaTypeId] INT NOT NULL,
[Data] VARBINARY(MAX) FILESTREAM NOT NULL);
```

I'm getting the below error:

> SQL46010; Incorrect syntax near FILESTREAM.

I've checked the basic syntax required to create a standard table with FILESTREAM support ([Click Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645583.aspx)) and my syntax appears fine to me, so I am guessing it is project specific.

Any help would be great - thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a mistake in my requirement - I am using the UDTT to bulk insert media data, however it is acceptable to store this as VARBINARY(MAX) in the UDTT and then SELECT-INSERT this in to a real table configured with a FILESTREAM column as below:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Media]
(
[Id] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
[Guid] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL ROWGUIDCOL,
[MediaTypeId] INT NOT NULL,
[Data] VARBINARY(MAX) FILESTREAM NOT NULL
)
```

It is not correct to have a FILESTREAM column type in a UDTT.